Iptables: Redirect IP matched request to dedicated server port
I have an iptables configuration problem that I cannot seem to solve.
I have a list of known, bad ip address that I block access to my server via ipset and iptables.
The original approach has been to simply drop the connection via iptables if an IP matches the ipset list.
And this worked just fine.
Now I decided to show a short server message instead of silently dropping the connection.
I want to inform the visitor that access was blocked and provide instructions to resolve this, if he/she feels the block is unwarranted.
My revised appraoch is as follows, but please comment if you have a better solution:
since, AFAIK, iptables cannot simply return a custom response for the request (please correct if wrong, I know that reject can return some fixed response codes, but not custom messages), I want to redirect the matched/identified IP address to a dedicated 8911 port on the Nginx server, so that I can then handle the request in Nginx and return the error message.
The Nginx instance is hosted in a Docker container.
These are the two (2) iptables rules that I inserted into the NAT table to re-route http and https requests to the dedciated 8911 port if the IP got matched:
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8911
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8911

this is the NAT table after I inserted the rules:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https match-set badips src,dst to:127.0.0.1:8911
2    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http match-set badips src,dst to:127.0.0.1:8911
3    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.23.0.0/16        anywhere
2    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.16.0.0/16        anywhere
3    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.23.0.14          172.23.0.14          tcp dpt:8911
4    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.23.0.14          172.23.0.14          tcp dpt:https
5    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.23.0.14          172.23.0.14          tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8911 to:172.23.0.14:8911
4    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:172.23.0.14:443
5    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:172.23.0.14:80

As you can see the dedicated 8911 port is open on the Nginx Docker container (port is currently open to the outside world for testing, this will then later be made only accessible to the server host).
this is the Nginx server block config for the dedicated 8911 port:
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8911;
    server_name _;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    error_page 403 /e403.html;

    location /e403.html{
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/error;
        access_log off;
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        access_log off;
        return 403;
    }
}

The Docker and Nginx config itself for the dedicatd 8911 port works, b/c when I directly access the dedicated 8911 port via curl or web browser from a good (non-matched) IP, the correct error response is returned with status 403.
Unfortunately, when accessing the server with a blocked IP, iptables does NOT redirect the request to the dedicated 8911 port.
The connection attempt times out (does not return anything), same as if the connection was simply dropped by iptables.
I have also changed the --to-destination IP (in the iptables rules) from  127.0.0.1 to either 0.0.0.0 or 172.23.0.14 (Docker interface) - it does not work.
My questions are:
(1) What must I change in my iptables rules to correctly redirect the IP matched request to the dedicated 8911 port?
(2) once iptables finally redirects the IP matched request correctly, would a https request that was IP matched (1st PREROUTING rule above) be re-directed to http with the dedicated 8911 port? e.g. https://foo.bar -> http://foo.bar:8911
(3) do you have any suggestions/recommendations for other approaches how to quick and efficiently serve an error response for IP matched requests?
UPDATE 2024.04.20:
removed the previous NAT prerouting rules and added these rules as suggested:
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8911
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8912

the NAT table now looks like this:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https match-set badips src,dst redir ports 8912
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http match-set badips src,dst redir ports 8911
3    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            !localhost/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.25.0.0/16        anywhere
2    MASQUERADE  all  --  172.16.0.0/16        anywhere
6    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.25.0.13          172.25.0.13          tcp dpt:8912
7    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.25.0.13          172.25.0.13          tcp dpt:8911
8    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.25.0.13          172.25.0.13          tcp dpt:https
9    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.25.0.13          172.25.0.13          tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8912 to:172.25.0.13:8912
7    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8911 to:172.25.0.13:8911
8    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https to:172.25.0.13:443
9    DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:172.25.0.13:80

also added an additional nginx server block for the port 8912 https redirect that loads the correct SSL cert...
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:8912 ssl http2;
    server_name _;
    include conf.d/my_server.cf;
    default_type text/plain;
    return 403 "IP address blocked for security reasons.";
}

this is the iptables filter table cfg:
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
7    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
8    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
9    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
7    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8    DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
9    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
10   ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
11   ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
12   ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
13   ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
14   ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
15   ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
16   ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
4    ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
5    ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
6    ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.29.0.13          tcp dpt:8912
5    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.29.0.13          tcp dpt:8911
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.29.0.13          tcp dpt:https
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.29.0.13          tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
3    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
2    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
3    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
4    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
5    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
6    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
7    ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
3    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
4    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
5    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
6    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
7    ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
4    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
5    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
6    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
7    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
8    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
9    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
10   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
11   ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
12   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             mdns.mcast.net       udp dpt:mdns
13   ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
14   ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
2    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
2    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
3    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
4    ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
5    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9933
2    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9933
3               tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
4    ufw-user-limit  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 30 hit_count: 6 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
5    ufw-user-limit-accept  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2375
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2376
8    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain ufw-user-limit (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
2    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

but:
(1) the iptables re-direct to port 8911/8912 does still NOT work
Thanks!

Possible Duplicate: Nginx - How to redirect users with certain IP to special page. However, iptables is not imho the correct answer. and as it seems in the current point of view, you did no research imho

@djdomi: I did research this, which is why my OP is so detailed. unfortunately, u did not provide a solution. Last, I already read the post you linked to, but it uses nginx/apache server logic to filter IPs which is not desirable b/c of the extra processing overhead, especially if you have a larger IP list... ipset w/ iptables is much more resource efficient...

Your configuration for port 8912 is not correct in nginx, It is not defined as https (lacks the ssl option and certificate definitions). Please share the definitions of the filter table.

@TeroKilkanen: thanks for spotting the nginx server block misconfig, fixed that (see above) - directly browsing to 8912 port via https now does show the msg. but iptables redirect still does NOT work. I added the filter table output to the OP as requested. Thanks !

I updated my answer with firewall suggestion.

DNAT target should be used when the target host is in the network behind the router where iptables is running.
However, in your case it is in the same machine. Therefore I suggest you use the REDIRECT target as follows:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8911

Also, you need a separate https port in your nginx. HTTP and TLS are two different protocols and you cannot run them on the same port.
Therefore you need to set up another virtual host with proper certificates on port 8912 for example, and then have the rule:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -m set --match-set badips src,dst -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8912

Your firewall rules seem to block incoming connections to ports 8911 and 8912.
You need to allow those ports using UFW.

Hi Tero, thank you for the answer. I made the changes you suggested and added an update to the OP, please see OP above. It still does not redirect an IP block to these ports. Let me know what you think please.

thank you for the update! Could you please add an example for the iptables cmd needed to allow a port in UFW?

Since the firewall is managed by UFW, the rule should be added with the ufw tool. Unfortunately I haven´t used UFW myself, so I cannot help with the command.

I'm quite honestly confused that Docker did not open these ports as port 8911/8912 are opened in docker-compose.yml  for the Nginx service., but maybe this port redirect we're doing via iptables requires that.. (?)

Docker compose likely exposes ports from the container to the outside host. But exposing ports to outside world is another thing that requires firewall changes. And Docker cannot know the external firewall setup, so it cannot modify it.

docker always adds all the required fw changes, it does this with all other ports that one exposes to the outside world or just the internal server host - e.g. for our MySQL or Redis docker services, all exposed ports are correctly configured by Docker in the fw - so since I added port 8911 and 8912 to the Nginx service cfg it should expose the ports correctly - as stated in the OP, I can access both 8911 / 8912 ports from the outside world via web browser and see my server msg, hence I'm confused why iptables or ufw would need extra changes for our port redirect... (?)

It is just because of the port redirect. Connections to Docker network namespace are routed, but redirected connections are destined to the host itself.

ok, if you could please add an example to your answer on how to modify the ufw in order to allow the port redirect, then I can test and accept this!
